# vscode ec2 pem key file connection problem

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nginx, amazon-ec2, pem

vscode ftp-simple Config.

```
    {
        "name": "ServerName",
        "host": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
        "port": 22,
        "type": "sftp",
        "username": "ubuntu",
        "password": "",
        "path": "/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true,
        "privateKey": "C:\\pv_key\\testkey.pem"
    }
```

Remote Derectory Open

> [vscode error]  Connect fail : Error: All configured authentication methods failed

- fileZilla : connect success!
- NotePad++ : connect success!
- Putty : -> ppk file convert connect success!
- ssh -i : connect success!
- status : pem key file chmod 400

Why can't only vscode connect? help...

Comment: You may want to check this similar question: [How to Connect EC2 Instance with VSCode Directly using pem file in SFTP] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402104/how-to-connect-ec2-instance-with-vscode-directly-using-pem-file-in-sftp)